# Visual Studio auto-saving on exit

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and when I exit without saving the project I'm working on, VS just saves it for me without asking. The behavior I'd expect is that if I exit without saving, VS would prompt me with the option to save or not. I can't seem to find the appropriate place to change this behavior in VS, nor can I find documentation of similar problems through searching.

I am using VS for BIDS projects, SSIS and SSRS.

Version Info:
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
Version 9.0.30729.4462 QFE

Comment: What add-ins you have installed and running? What macros do you have in `MyMacros.EnvironmentEvents`?

Comment: There are no add-ins installed. Environment Events has only automatically generated code defining event sources.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is probably saving the project when you compile / build the project.  You may consider [version control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181368.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#yes_or_no).

Comment: I have read about the auto-save related to compiling/building, but I believe this is a different issue. I specifically tested it without compiling or building the project, and it still occurred.

Comment: I take that back, previewing the report was compiling it, which was then automatically saving it. Closing without previewing caused VS to prompt about saving. Changing the options related to automatically saving when compiling should correct the issue.